# How to rotate an image in SSRS

Tags: css, vb.net, reporting-services

I am building a report in SSRS using SQL where I an converting a barcode into an image using the code below, this code was taken from [here](http://www.zeninteractions.com/free-reporting-services-barcodes). I am not a `VB.Net` developer but this code works perfectly for me. 
The issue is that the layout of my report is with a vertical barcode image rather than horizontal, and I don't see any option where I can rotate the image OOB. Can anyone help me here to rotate the image using the below code.

```
Public Shared Function GenerateImage(ByVal fontName As String, ByVal stringText As String) As Byte()

    Dim oGraphics As System.Drawing.Graphics
    Dim barcodeSize As System.Drawing.SizeF
    Dim ms As System.IO.MemoryStream
    Dim i As System.Drawing.Image

    Using font As New System.Drawing.Font(New System.Drawing.FontFamily(fontName), 36)
    Using tmpBitmap As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(1, 1, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    oGraphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(tmpBitmap)
    oGraphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel

    barcodeSize = oGraphics.MeasureString(stringText, font)
    oGraphics.Dispose()
    End Using

    Using newBitmap As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(barcodeSize.Width, barcodeSize.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    oGraphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap)
    oGraphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel


    Using oSolidBrushWhite As New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.White)
    Using oSolidBrushBlack As New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black)
    oGraphics.FillRectangle(oSolidBrushWhite, New System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, barcodeSize.Width, barcodeSize.Height))
    oGraphics.DrawString(stringText, font, oSolidBrushBlack, 0, 0)

    End Using

    End Using

    ms = New System.IO.MemoryStream()
    newBitmap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
    End Using
        End Using

    Return ms.ToArray()
    End Function
```

I am absolutely a NOOB in VB.Net.

Comment: you may just need `bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone)` or similar depending on which direction it is flipped.

Comment: @Plutonix - [Appears to work for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rAtUp.png)

Comment: Changes to the sample project were adding `newBitmap.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone)` before `newBitmap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)` and setting ImageProperties in the report to "Original Size" rather than "Clip" BTW.

Comment: added as an answer with some other observations/tips

Comment: I get the following error when I add the code and try to run the report `Name RotateFlipType is not declared`.

Comment: And I have already added `System.Drawing` assembly reference in my report properties in SSRS

Comment: @hkhan Reference it using the fully qualified name per my earlier comment. You might be able to add an `imports System.Drawing` but I see the rest of your example code doesn't do that so maybe this isn't possible in the RS embedded code.

Comment: @Martin Smith, Thank you that worked well :D Can you post your comment as answer so I can mark it?

Comment: @hkhan It is Plutonix's answer really. Hopefully he/she just edits their answer to work in reporting services.

Comment: @Martin Smith, this is IT community at its best. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Bitmap` class has several built in rotate and flip mechanisms:

```
Dim bmp As Bitmap = <bitmap from somewhere>

bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone)
```

This rotates the image 270 degrees CW, the same as 90 CCW.  Many other rotation options exist such as:

```
Rotate270FlipXY
Rotate270FlipY
Rotate270FlipX
```

As well as variants based on `Rotate90...` and `Rotate180...`

---

I should also point out that rather than nesting Using statements, you can combine them:

```
Using font As New Font(New FontFamily(fontName), 36),
       tmpBitmap As New Bitmap(1, 1, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
       Br As New Brush(.....),
       otherBMP As New Bitmap(....)

       <your code here>

                       <rather than here>
```

This reduces the amount of indentation imposed on the code which many find annnoying.  You can also shorten some of those references such as `System.Drawing.Font` by adding an `Imports` statement at the top (`using` in C#):

```
Imports System.Drawing
```

(apparently you cannot currently use `Imports` with SSRS as the links in the comment, so ignore that part).

Comment: [Looks like `imports` can't be used in this context](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/960d0956-804d-4cf2-9c2a-e6e654d21964/ssrs-and-imports)

Comment: could you please put an functional example/explanation ?